# Multiple solutions versus unique solution while solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following problem is taken from Prof Joseph Cutrone's precalculus course in Coursera - (https://www.coursera.org/learn/precalculus-relations-functions/lecture/oaxfd/properties-of-logarithms). A screenshot of the problem is below.

Solve for x: $ln\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{ln\,x}$

| Solution | Alternate Solution |
| --- | --- |
| $ln\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{ln\,x}$ |  |
| $ln\,x^{1/2}=(ln\,x)^{1/2}$ |  |
| $\frac{1}{2}\,ln\,x=(ln\,x)^{1/2}$ |  |
| $(\frac{1}{2}\,ln\,x)^2=((ln\,x)^{1/2})^2$ |  |
| $(\frac{1}{2}\,ln\,x)^2=ln\,x$ | $(\frac{1}{2}\,ln\,x)^2=ln\,x$ |
| $\frac{1}{4}\,(ln\,x)^2=ln\,x$ | $\frac{1}{4}\,(ln\,x)^2=ln\,x$ |
| $\frac{1}{4}\,(ln\,x)^2-ln\,x=0$ | $\frac{1}{4}\,\frac{(ln\,x)^2}{ln\,x}=\frac{ln\,x}{ln\,x}$ |
| $(ln\,x)\,(\frac{1}{4}\,ln\,x-1)=0$ - $ln\,x=0$ - $\frac{1}{4}\,ln\,x-1=0$ | $\frac{1}{4}\,(ln\,x)=1$ |
| - $ln\,x=0$ - $\frac{1}{4}\,ln\,x=1$ | $ln\,x=4$ |
| - $ln\,x=0$ - $ln\,x=4$ | $e^{ln\,x}=e^4$ |
| - $e^{ln\,x}=e^0$ - $e^{ln\,x}=e^4$ | $x=e^4$ |
| - $x=1$ - $x=e^4$ |  |

The question I have is - is the alternate solution incorrect ? How come the alternate solution give us only one of the solutions to $x$ ?

[Professor's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG2TM.png)

Comment: In the alternate solution you divided by $\ln(x)$ on both sides. To be able to do this you need to assume that $\ln(x)\neq 0$. However, note that $\ln(1)=0$. This is why one of the solutions dissapeared.

Comment: You could make your alternate solution correct by considering the case that $\ln(x)\neq 0$ case (as you have done correctly) and $\ln(x)=0$ case separately.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.

Comment: your professors solution is right, $$x=1$$ or $$x=e^4$$